# How to prevent Browsersync from refreshing scss

Tags: reactjs, sass, browser-sync

I'm working with laravel and react, and installed browsersync to speed things up. 
However, I noticed on the CMD that it keeps detecting changes to the .scss file and re-builds, literally non stop.
It's my first time using BS, and I couldn't track the reason for this.
[image]

edit: Apparently I did something wrong while adding a custom font. I moved it directly to public/fonts, instead of adding to assets/fonts and having webpack move it to public/fonts. Fixing this solved the issue.

Comment: Probably you need to set the filter so that it doesn't watch the folder where built files go.

Comment: I tried that just now, but no difference. Probably didnt do it properly. 
    mix.browserSync({
     watchOptions: {
         ignoreInitial: true,
         ignored: "*.scss"
     }
 });

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I did something wrong while adding a custom font. I moved it directly to public/fonts, instead of adding to assets/fonts and having webpack move it to public/fonts. Fixing this solved the issue.